# Google Tag Manager Trigger using RegEx

Tags: regex, google-tag-manager

I'm troubleshooting an event that uses an 'All Elements' trigger associated to a 'Click Class' lookup table.

The lookup table has four input values corresponding to classes added to target HTML elements. The event needs to fire when any target element is clicked.

From what I can determine through testing, if a clicked element has more than one class (including one of the target click classes), the Lookup table as I've configured it does not receive the value (the eventLabel holds the lookup variable is null) and the trigger does not fire. I've verified that the class is present in the datalayer, in the click class variable.

The LookUp table passes unique output values for each input, and the trigger has a simple regex, as follows:

Trigger fires when 'My LookUp Variable' matches RegEx (ignore case) heading|button|image

The only time it fires is when the heading is clicked -- this is the element that has only the target class. All other elements have other classes in addition to the target class.

Also, I'd use click ID for this but the target elements exist within a search result component that appears many times on the webpage. Hence, use of the ID attribute would be semantically incorrect.

Anyway...any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Lookup table only works for exact matches. The unavoidable Simo Ahava has written a post on a custom javascript regex lookup function that you could adapt for your use case: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/simple-regex-lookup-table-for-google-tag-manager/

Comment: Simo is indeed awesome. I adapted his script (thankyou for the pointer) but it hasn't resolved the issue. What's odd is that I also edited the value passed with no match, but it (the default value) isn't passed with the Javascript variable.